# How do I get rtags to work in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, rtags

On a recent pull of both rtags and spacemacs, but I can't seem to get rtags to work well. There is no keybindings for jumping/searching to/for symbols and the definitions either. I've seen a couple places that that about either mineo layer or that c++-mode itself has support, but I can't find the magic words.

I have c-c++-backend set to 'rtags but it still keeps asking me what tags file I want to use. I already have rdm up and running and I get queries back from it, so that isn't an issue.

What is the current way to use rtags in c++-node for spacemacs?

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is not a quite easy task !

Try to add the following in your .spacemacs file:

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(c-c++
  (c-c++ :variables c-c++-default-mode-for-headers 'c++-mode)
  (c-c++ :variables c-c++-backend 'rtags))
```

On the other hand, you may check if your rdm server works fine by running something like `rc -s fileids` from terminal. This is just to check your database is up and consistent.

Let me know if it works for you...